# Is there a standard notation for left and right division in a ring?

Tags: ring-theory, notation, soft-question

In a commutative ring $R$, if $a$ and $b$ are elements of $R$ we say that $a$ *divides* $b$ if and only if there is some $c\in R$ such that $ac=b.$ A standard notation for this is $a\mid b$.

Now in a general ring (not necessarily commutative), we may say that $a$ *left-divides* $b$ if there is an element $c$ such that $ac=b$ and *right-divides* $b$ if there is an element $d$ such that $da=b$ (I may have permuted the names). I am not aware of any notation to distinguish between the two, is there a generally accepted choice? Perhaps $a\mid_l b$ and $a\mid_r b$?

Comment: Your page title (which reverse to *division*) seems to not match your question (which refers to *divisibility*).

Answer (score 2):

I think most people would just write $b\in Ra$ for "right-divides" (as you've written it) and be done with it.